# Approach to make data-hub using spring-integration?

Tags: spring-integration

I want to make my own data hub using spring integration.
it will be big data hub having a lots of data.

For example, One of patterns in the data-hub is like the followings.

```
 GateWay  ---   projects tasks --- commits  tasks --- ----- finish
          |                    |                 |      |
          |                    -- branches tasks -      |
          |                                             |
          ---  users task-------------------------------
```

Each tasks have to receive the json data from the application where they provides open api through http rest. I already made this logic using spring integration. But every time I add the pattern, I can't add the annotation and xml configurations. How can I make this flexible? even if I add the pattern I want to add code at least. There are various patterns that have to be adapted.
Is there any good references for making framework structure?